# Is there a name for this "fill in the blank" algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

This problem might be hard to describe, I'll try to boil it down as much as possible.

Input data is a list of number arrays, which represent the indices that a word can possibly fit into.

The text could be much more complicated, but
for example:

```
const text = "I eat ___ and ___. Also, I grow ___ and ___."
const words = ["cookies", "carrots", "flowers", "cucumbers"]
const possibleBlanks = [[0,1], [0,1,2,3], [2,3], [1,2,3,4]]
```

Notice how, a word can *possibly* fit into a blank meaning it makes sense English wise; but given the challenge that all blanks need to be filled, some "possible blanks" will be off limits for some words. For in the above example, cucumbers and carrots could both fit in the first two slots, but that would make the rest impossible to solve with the remaining words.

What I'm trying to solve is: words needs to be labeled correct or incorrect if it assigned to a blank.

I thought this problem would be easy (they seem easy to solve as a human) but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Things I initially tried but realized was flawed:

- Grouping words as interchangeable. For example, this could work when blanks are separated by "and". But this doesn't work when words can fit in various slots, like in the example above you can't eat flowers, so they are only interchangeable with cucumbers if cucumbers is also after "growing" and not "eat".
- Attempting to "remove" any impossible indices AOT as a solution. For example, if one word can only occur in blank[2], then 2 would be removed from all arrays in possibleBlanks. But, this isn't a valid solution since whether a blank index is valid for a word can depend on and change when a user selects a word.
- Setting up the possibleBlanks as a matrix each row being populated with values of the arrays (a 1 for each corresponding index, 0 otherwise), then subtracting the next row up to the one below. My idea was if we populated with longest arrays on the bottom, we'd be left with a row of zeros if no solution. Also a bit of edge case handling, like if rows are identical don't subtract, but gave up on this idea, since it seemed impossible to handle all cases.

So after coming up with no solution I could only think of brute forcing it, starting with the arrays that are the shortest in length, picking a index and then repeat with the next index. If it ends up valid word order then done, if not then repeat over again.

Hoping someone can mention a better algorithm, maybe this problem has a name?

---

**Edit**:
I'm taking linear algebra 1 at the moment, so I guess my mind is a bit biased to think in terms of matrices.

Here is the best I could think of:

If you make a matrix where the rows are words, and the columns are blanks (such that each entry in the matrix is only filled if the corresponding word can possibly fill the corresponding blank).

I made the mistake in thinking if each column has a filled entry, then a solution exists. This isn't true though, since an obvious counter example is one word that can possibly fill all blanks (if there is more blanks to fill, once we use that word, the row is removed from the matrix so there could be no solution).

Using the same matrix, a solution exists we we can re-arrange the rows such that a diagonal series of entries are filled that crosses over the entire matrix. This feels a bit easier to work with, but I still couldn't find a way of solving it, other than maybe improving the brute force algorithm (select first words with smallest amount of possible blanks that are unfilled, but wasn't able to prove that would work).

After reading the posted answers, I'm very grateful and relieved I can now learn more about this type of problem. For my specific case, the Hopcroft–Karp algorithm should be a good choice (if I understand correctly). I don't understand any of this yet, but look forward to learn about it in the future. Thank you all for the wonderful help.

Comment: Do you wish to find a single "valid" assignment of words to locations, if one exists, or do you wish to generate all such assignments?

Comment: Looks like bipartite graph matching problem (perhaps maximum matching )

Comment: @CarySwoveland This is something I was contemplating a lot today. A single valid assignment is all I need. I'd be totally interested if there is a clever way to generate all solutions.

Comment: This problem looks similar to solving Sudokus, only that there are expected to be 0-N solutions. Searching for Sudoku solver algorithms you might be able to find some good inspiration.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Sudoku has an added constraint: when you put a number in a cell, not only does this number occupy this cell, but it also affects what can be put in some other cells. Also in sudoku you have nine of each number to place, whereas in the OP's problem each word appears to be more or less unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a type of linear programming ("LP") problem called an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). As explained at the link it can be solved as a general LP problem (with the Simplex Method, say) or solved with an algorithm designed specifically for assignment problems.

LP problems are characterized by:

- *variables* whose values are to be determined;
- an *objective function*, equal to a linear function of the variables, whose value is to be minimized or maximized; and
- *constraints*, being linear functions of the variables, that must be satisfied.

**The variables**

x<sub>ij</sub> equals:

```
 1 if word `i` is assigned to location `j`
 0 if word `i` is not assigned to location `j`
```

for each word `i` and location `j`

**Objective function**

We nave

minimize Σ<sub>i,j</sub>c<sub>ij</sub>x<sub>ij</sub>

where c<sub>ij</sub> equals `0` if `j` is a permitted location for word `i` and equals `1` otherwise.

**Constraints**

Σ<sub>j</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each word `i` where the summation is over all locations `j`; and

Σ<sub>i</sub>x<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for each location `j`, where the summation is over all words `i`.

0 <= x<sub>ij</sub> <= 1 for each pair of word `i` and location `j`

There is an additional requirement that each x<sub>ij</sub> can only take on the value `0` or `1`, but no explicit constraints are needed to enforce that requirement. As explained at the link, while the variables in LP problems are permitted to take on fractional values, an important characteristic of assignment problems is that there will always exist an optional solution in which all variables equal `0` or `1`.

---

It is evident that there exists an assignment that meets the stated location requirements if and only if the value of the optimal solution (i.e., the value of the objective function for optimal values of the variables) equals zero.

---

Consider the example given in the question:

"I eat ___ and ___. Also, I grow ___ and ___."
["cookies", "carrots", "flowers", "cucumbers"]
[[0,1], [0,1,2,3], [2,3], [1,2,3]]

(Note that I changed the array for cucumbers from `[1,2,3,4]` to `[1,2,3]` as there is no location `4`.)

The formulation of the assignment problem is as follows.

*Variables*

x<sub>coo,0</sub>, x<sub>coo,1</sub>, x<sub>coo,2</sub>, x<sub>coo,3</sub>

x<sub>car,0</sub>, x<sub>car,1</sub>, x<sub>car,2</sub>, x<sub>car,3</sub>

x<sub>flo,0</sub>, x<sub>flo,1</sub>, x<sub>flo,2</sub>, x<sub>flo,3</sub>

x<sub>cuc,0</sub>, x<sub>cuc,1</sub>, x<sub>cuc,2</sub>, x<sub>cuc,3</sub>

*Cost coefficients in objective function*

All cost coefficients equal '0' except for the following, which equal `1`:

c<sub>coo,2</sub>, c<sub>coo,3</sub>

c<sub>flo,0</sub>, c<sub>flo,1</sub>

c<sub>cuc,0</sub>

Each word must be assigned to a location

x<sub>coo,0</sub> + x<sub>coo,1</sub> + x<sub>coo,2</sub> + x<sub>coo,3</sub> = 1

x<sub>car,0</sub> + x<sub>car,1</sub> + x<sub>car,2</sub> + x<sub>car,3</sub> = 1

x<sub>flo,0</sub> + x<sub>flo,1</sub> + x<sub>flo,2</sub> + x<sub>flo,3</sub> = 1

x<sub>cuc,0</sub> + x<sub>cuc,1</sub> + x<sub>cuc,2</sub> + x<sub>cuc,3</sub> = 1

A word is assigned to each location

x<sub>coo,0</sub> + x<sub>car,0</sub> + x<sub>flo,0</sub> + x<sub>cuc,0</sub> = 1

x<sub>coo,1</sub> + x<sub>car,1</sub> + x<sub>flo,1</sub> + x<sub>cuc,1</sub> = 1

x<sub>coo,2</sub> + x<sub>car,2</sub> + x<sub>flo,2</sub> + x<sub>cuc,2</sub> = 1

x<sub>coo,3</sub> + x<sub>car,3</sub> + x<sub>flo,3</sub> + x<sub>cuc,3</sub> = 1

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation! It's so helpful to know what type of problem it is. I've never learned about this type of problem or LP, so I really appreciate you breaking down to simple case I can understand. From briefly reading it seems to me that the hopcroft_karp_matching algorithm MBo displayed is a best choice for me, it should work for the specifics for my problem I think. I look forward to learning about linear programming in the future. I guess should also mention, I deleted my answer but added it to my original post since it wrong. Thanks again for the great post.

Comment: Buretto, I understand. You should consider moving the green checkmark to @MBo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Example of solving problem as maximal cardinality matching for bipartite graph using Python networkx

```
import networkx as nx
text = "I eat ___ and ___. Also, I grow ___ and ___."
words = ["cookies", "carrots", "flowers", "cucumbers"]
possibleBlanks = [[0,1], [0,1,2,3], [2,3], [0,1,2,3]]
B = nx.Graph()
B.add_nodes_from([0, 1, 2, 3], bipartite=0)
B.add_nodes_from(words, bipartite=1)
edges = []
for i, w in enumerate(words):
    for p in possibleBlanks[i]:
        edges.append((w, p))
B.add_edges_from(edges)
matches = nx.bipartite.hopcroft_karp_matching(B)
for w in words:
    print(w, matches[w])
```

Result

```
cookies 0
carrots 1
flowers 2
cucumbers 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into a a backtracking search algorithm-  basically depth first search.  Basically you pick a value for blank 1.  Then for blank 2, then 3, etc.  Keep going until all blanks are filled (this is a possible solution) or until no valid option remains (this is a failure and you backtrack to the previous state).

Pseudocode:

```
bool search(int slotNumber, int totalSlots, list<String> usedWords)  {
   if(slotNumber == totalSlots) {
       return true
   }
   possibleWords= legalWordsForThisSlot(slotNum, usedWords)
   possibleWords.forEach { currentWord->
      if(search(slotNumber+1, totalSlots, usedWords+currentWord) == true) {
          return true
      }
   }
   return false
}
```

You'd call it initially as `search(0, 4, emptyList())`.  Yes, this is brute forcing things, but this is a general algorithm that would work for any search of this sort. I'd then look for better algorithms only if N is so high as to make this unviable due to runtime.  And even then, your solution will likely be a variation of this with some brains to optimize what slots you assign first (for example, don't fill in slots from 0 to 4, fill in slots from the fewest options to the most to reduce branchout)

Comment: My thoughts exactly when I started this problem. I was a bit scatter brained and couldn't put it so succinctly. This is what I meant from my brute force thing I was settling on. Thanks for making it more clear, appreciate it.

Comment: This backtracking bruteforce algorithm is somewhat unavoidable for complicated constraint problems like sudoku, but for a simple problem like yours @Buretto , I think MBo's approach is much more efficient.